# find value of closet input when clicking a link

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of text inputs with a link to the right of each

```
<p><input type="text" name="color[]" value="orange" /> <a href="#" class="show-color">color</a><br />
<input type="text" name="color[]" value="purple" /> <a href="#" class="show-color">color</a><br />
<input type="text" name="color[]" value="blue" /> <a href="#" class="show-color">color</a></p>
```

I want to find out the value of the input field that is next to the link I clicked, using jQuery, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**prev()**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method of jquery to find the previous element on click of anchor,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vD5NA/)**

```
$('.show-color').click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev().val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.show-color').click(function(){
alert($(this).prev().val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is `prev` not `next` as the input is before the link tag.

```
$('.show-color').click(function () {
   alert($(this).prev().val());
});
```